# Where can I find the silencer for the 1960's Pistol?

Tags: wolfenstein-the-new-order

I found the silencer for the classic (Luger?) pistol, but I seem to have missed its corresponding upgrade for the "Handgun 1960". Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually at least two locations for it, both are missable.

- **The Asylum level**: "*You get this in the Asylum before you go outside. Look for the barricade in the hallway in the first area. Above that barricade you can gain access to the roof and get the silencer for the pistol.*" [(Source)](http://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/wolfenstein-new-order-guide-weapon-upgrade-location-guide/)
- **Chapter 10**: As you ride the elevator up after drudging through the Berlin Catacombs, you'll find the LaserKraftWerk Tesla Upgrade straight ahead. In that same room, in the left-most corner as you exit the elevator you can find a Silence Pistol if you missed the asylym upgrade.